# Distribution function of discrete variable with three variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm learning distribution functions from my course of probabilities, but this is the first time I see a distribution with three variables, as follows:

A company offers three services: A, B and C. They perform them randomly, with probabilities 1/2, 3/10 and 1/5 respectively, and the price of these services are respectively 5, 10 and 20 USD. Per day 4 jobs are performed randomly, determine the distribution function for the daily income of this company.

I would appreciate any feedback to help me get into the problem.

Comment: Identify the supported incomes, the probabilities for each, and from this the *cumulative distribution function* for the income.

Comment: These are not "three variables". There's a random variable here (service type), which can take three values (A,B,C). And you there's a second random variable (daily income) which is related to the previous one.